# Is there plans for Meteor to support Gentoo?

Tags: installation, meteor, gentoo

I operate Gentoo systems, will Meteor support for Gentoo be available at some point? Is there a way I can install on Gentoo now?

Thank you
Chuck

Comment: Meteor is available in Portage, currently keyworded unstable.

Answer (score 3):

**Will Meteor support for Gentoo be available at some point?**

Meteor is now available in Portage, currently keyworded unstable.

**Is there a way I can install on Gentoo now?**

Yes, you can execute the following commands to install it:

```bash
echo "www-servers/meteor" >> /etc/portage/package.accept_keywords
emerge --sync 
emerge -av www-servers/meteor
```

Please file any problems you encounter with it at **[bugs.gentoo.org](https://bugs.gentoo.org)**. For generic help with Gentoo or Portage you can try the IRC channel #gentoo on the FreeNode network, or their forums.

---

I recommend you to use **[Zugaina](http://gpo.zugaina.org/)** everytime you need to search for a package not yet available in the "gentoo" overlay. As I write this Zugaina returns [results for "meteor"](http://gpo.zugaina.org/Search?search=meteor). If it wouldn't, you could search **[bugs.gentoo.org](https://bugs.gentoo.org)** for user contributed ebuilds, like [this](https://bugs.gentoo.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=meteor).

If you ever need to do a new ebuild/package request, please go to [bugs.gentoo.org](https://bugs.gentoo.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Gentoo%20Linux), select the "ebuild" Component, provide some info about the package you're requesting (name, website, ...) and hit submit.